# Use a unique alias in WebPack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

Currently in my WebPack 5 I use the following configuration, where I manually enter aliases, even if they all follow the same patter,
How to be less verbose and have this configuration in a more generic way?

```
config.resolve.alias['components'] = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
config.resolve.alias['logic'] = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/logic')
// more here
```

Comment: You could define a `@` alias for you src directory and do `@/components`, `@/logic` ...

Comment: could you please provide me an example? thanks

Comment: I use this : `'@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/src'),` you could adapt it to your case, and then `import User from "@/models/user"` for example, or whatever you want to import. If you create a new directory in src, it will still work with '`@/mynewdirectory`, and you don't need to add a new alias each time